# How do I hide the names of collaborators when coding in the Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: cloud9-ide

I share my project with another developer, and the Cloud9 IDE underlines the code he wrote with his name, and my code with my name. It also shows colours in the margins indicating who wrote which parts. How do I hide this? I haven't been able to find an option for this in the settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting is called `Show authorship info` in the `settings>Collaboration` section of preferences panel